# variable created with "let" in global scope vs variable created with "var" inside a loop

Tags: javascript, variables

I am trying to get some experience with the variable declarations in JavaScript.
in the following code, whenever I try to define the variable inside the loop with var keyword it throws me an error:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'i' has already been declared".

whereas if I use "let" keyword (or no keyword at all) there is no problem.
I know that in the case that I don't use any keyword, JavaScript uses the same variable in the global scope and overwrites it. 
I also know that variables created with "let" keyword are considered block scope and variables created with "var" keyword outside a function are considered global. but I don't understand this behavior!
I would be grateful if anybody could shed illumination on this matter.

this code:

```
let i = 78;
console.log(i);
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    var insideloop = 100;
}
```

console.log(i);
gives this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'i' has already been declared

but this one has no problem an gives the following output:

```
let i = 78;
console.log(i);
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    var insideloop = 100;
}
console.log(i);
```

Results:
78
0
1
2
3
78

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var). it's because of the scope.

Answer (score 0):

The variables declared with `var` inside any block in the global scope are not local to that block(in your case its block of `for` loop) but they are inside global scope.

So in your first example you are trying to re declare the variable `i` which is already declared before in global scope with `let`.

```js
for(var i =0;i<5;i++){}
console.log(i); //i is in global scope
```

Where as `let` if declared in any block in your case its limited to the block of for loop. Its not present outside.

```js
for(let i =0;i<5;i++){}
console.log(i); //i is in global scope
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply...
I understand what you say but, if I were to declare the external `i`  with `var` and redeclare it inside the loop, JavaScript would not complain and reassign the same variable with the new value! I assume that `var` keyword cannot overwrite a variable which has been created by `let` keyword. am I correct?

Comment: `var i = 78;
console.log(i);
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    var insideloop = 100;
}
console.log(i);`

Comment: in the case of the above code, JavaScript would not have a problem with reassigning the variable with the new value.